# How to change property value that having new C# 6.0 string interpolation to new referenced value?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, string-interpolation, c#-6.0

I have this class

```
public static class DateFormat
{
    public static string separator= "-";
    public static string DateFormat24H { get; set; } = $"yyyy{separator}MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
}
```

Now, when calling **DateFormat24** hours it will print **yyyy-MM/dd**. now change the **separator** variable

`DateFormat.separator = "/";` The **DateFormat24H** still the same **yyyy-MM/dd**

The string interpolation is assigned only in first initialization? So accessing the variable every time will use old string interpolation assigned? or am wrong. Or what I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Firstly**, your current code relies on the intalization order of your class, luckily it's the right order, but that is an implementation detail and may change

**Secondly**, the following property, is an auto-implemented property, you can think of it just like setting it in the constructor, it's never re-evaluated again

```
public static string DateFormat24H { get; set; } = $"yyyy{separator}MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
```

**Lastly**, What you are most likely looking for is a expression body definition to implement a read-only property. Which would look like this.

```
public static string DateFormat24H => $"yyyy{separator}MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
```

Every time you call it, it will reevaluate the interpolation

**Update**

> you see your Lastly, post. please can you gave full example of using
>   get; set; both so evaluating the separator. and set the property. i
>   mean using backing field or something like screenshot. prnt.sc/q22q0r
>   Please execuse me about that.

You can't do this with interpolation, you need to use `String.Format`
Example of settable property

```
private static string _separator = "/";

private static string _backing = "yyyy{0}MM/dd HH:mm:ss";

public static string DateFormat24H
{
   get => string.Format(_backing, _separator);
   set => _backing = value;
}
```

**Usage**

```
Console.WriteLine(DateFormat24H);
_separator = "@";
Console.WriteLine(DateFormat24H);
DateFormat24H = "yyyyMM{0}dd";
Console.WriteLine(DateFormat24H);
```

**Output**

```
yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss
yyyy@MM/dd HH:mm:ss
yyyyMM@dd
```

Comment: I like Lastly, it works and I never thought about it. but why auto-implemented property not evaluating again?

Comment: @asdk1200000 because they are initialised once and once only

Comment: What if I need both get and set?

Comment: Sorry, but why this not worked?? http://prntscr.com/q22q0r   you set value must included in get. so it will evaluated again. but see screenshot. output is same.

Comment: @asdk1200000 you cant do that, you cant save the interpolation to evaluate later in a getter like this which is changeable. it will evaluate when its set.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you have something like `MyProperty { get; set; } = "something";`, the value of "something" is the *default value* of the property. It is only assigned once.

Comment: TheGeneral, you see your Lastly, post. please can you gave full example of using get; set; both so evaluating the separator.  and set the property. i mean using backing field or something like screenshot. https://prnt.sc/q22q0r Please execuse me about that. :(

Comment: Interpolation works too -- just use `get => $"yyyy{separator}MM/dd HH:mm:ss";`

Comment: @Herohtar you cant set it though. which is what i thought op was after, though i must admit, i could be completely wrong

Comment: It looks to me like OP wanted to be able to set the separator and not the rest of the string -- that's the part they were attempting to change in the question.

Comment: @Herohtar yeah that was my first solution `DateFormat24H => $"yyyy{separator}MM/dd HH:mm:ss"` which should work and will evaluate every time